# Generar EXE para Windows diferentes Arquitecturas

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows

¿Cómo compilar una aplicación de escritorio de Python para Windows con PyInstaller?

El problema es la diferencia de arquitecturas, estoy usando PyInstaller para generar un EXE desde la arquitectura x64 al ejecutarlo en x86 me indica que hay un error en las arquitecturas y no se puede ejecutar.

La documentación de PyInstaller dice que no es posible generar el EXE desde diferentes Sistemas Operativos, por lo tanto, tampoco se puede si no es el mismo entorno.

¿Alguien conoce alguna alternativa a la solución?

El reinstalar un sistema operativo por cada arquitectura o sistema operativo en cada máquina instalando Python y PyInstaller (en los que sea necesario) no me parece una opción viable.

Answer (score 1):

Nunca antes he usado PyInstaller por lo tanto no se como funciona exactamente, lo que sí se es que los sistemas operativos Windows de 64 bits tienen la capacidad de ejecutar programas de 32 bits, pero esto no ocurre a la inversa que es lo que veo que estás tratando de hacer.

La solución me parece que es muy sencilla, utiliza un sistema de 32 bits para generar la aplicación, esta debería correr tanto en tus sistemas de 32 bits como de 64 bits.

Tendríamos que darle las gracias a [WOW64](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/WOW64).

Answer (score 1):

PyInstaller genera los .exe usando la instalación original de Python que tengas en el host, por ejemplo si tienes Python 2.7 para 64 bits no puedes generar un .exe de 32 ya que usa los dll's y dependencias de la instalación de Python para crear el ejecutable.